# Inferred to have type 'AnyClass', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
if let runningTests = NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") {
    return false
}
```

The compiler warning:

> "Constant 'runningTests' inferred to have type 'AnyClass', which may
>   be unexpected.

What is it I need to cast to to remove this warning without changing my code into a if != nil check on the result of NSClassFromString?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually mean `AnyClass` here, so you just need to tell the compiler that:

```
if let runningTests: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try that. On one attempt I tried to type it as AnyClass! - however that returned false every time instead of working as expected, although the compiler warning disappeared. Can you explain why please?

Comment: If you say that `runningTests` is of type `AnyClass!` then `NSClassFromString()` would have to return `AnyClasss!?` (or `AnyClass??` which is equivalent). Any optional optional is a valid (and sometimes useful) type.

Comment: That seems strange. So I could potentially add n number of ? marks after a variable to deeply box it into an optional multiple times. Please enlighten me to a use case of an optional optional. Thanks.

Comment: Consider the case of `first([T?])`. You have an array of optionals and you want to get the first element, which is itself an optional, since there may be no first element. So the return type would be `T??`.

Comment: This situation comes up a bit, BTW, when applying `map` over functions that return optionals. If you're not careful, you can wind up with rather crazy boxes. In other languages this is resolved with a function like `flatMap` (or `bind`, or at least `flatten`), but there isn't such a function in Swift, and you have to build your own: http://robnapier.net/flatmap